# triangulate points using epipolar geometry

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, triangulation, stereo-3d

I'm using in OpenCV the method

> triangulatePoints(P1,P2,x1,x2)

to get the 3D coordinates of a point by its image points x1/x2 in the left/right image and the projection matrices P1/P2.

I've already studied epipolar geometry and know most of the maths behind it. But what how does this algorithm get mathematically the 3D Coordinates?

Comment: are you able to extract the camera extrinsics from your epipolar geometry?

Comment: Yes, I already got the Extrinsic. They are in P1 and P2, aren't they?

Comment: I dont know. But in theory, if you know which points correspond to each other and where the cameras are (extrinsics) you can shoot a ray from the camera center through the pixel and where those rays intersect (in 3D) your point can be placed. In practice they wont intersect but come quite close to each other. In practice there's probably some way to overcome the "should intersect but doesnt" thing.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do! So I do not have to deal with this "should intersect but doesn't" problem, I just need the theoretical equation for these two rays and the intersection point (maybe through equating the left and right ray?). Do you know how to write these equations? Thanks a lot, you understand my problem!

Comment: did you read the openCV documentation? for most/many functions, literature information is provided there.

Comment: Yes, I did. But I didn't find anything neither in the documentation nor in the "multiple view geometry" book.

Comment: maybe this link tells you where to find the reference in zisserman: http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/01/04/simple-triangulation-with-opencv-from-harley-zisserman-w-code/ however see sozrce code to know how opencv does it

Answer (score 1):

Here are just some ideas, to the best of my knowledge, should at least work theoretically.

Using the camera equation `ax = PX`, we can express the two image point correspondences as

`ap = PX`

`bq = QX`

where `p = [p1 p2 1]'` and `q = [q1 q2 1]'` are the matching image points to the 3D point `X = [X Y Z 1]'` and `P` and `Q` are the two projection matrices.

We can expand these two equations and rearrange the terms to form an `Ax = b` system as shown below

`p11.X + p12.Y + p13.Z - a.p1 + b.0 = -p14`

`p21.X + p22.Y + p23.Z - a.p2 + b.0 = -p24`

`p31.X + p32.Y + p33.Z - a.1  + b.0 = -p34`

`q11.X + q12.Y + q13.Z + a.0 - b.q1 = -q14`

`q21.X + q22.Y + q23.Z + a.0 - b.q2 = -q24`

`q31.X + q32.Y + q33.Z + a.0 - b.1  = -q34`

from which we get

`A = [p11 p12 p13 -p1 0; p21 p22 p23 -p2 0; p31 p32 p33 -1 0; q11 q12 q13 0 -q1; q21 q22 q23 0 -q2; q31 q32 q33 0 -1]`, `x = [X Y Z a b]'` and `b = -[p14 p24 p34 q14 q24 q34]'`. Now we can solve for x to find the 3D coordinates.

Another approach is to use the fact, from camera equation `ax = PX`, that `x` and `PX` are parallel. Therefore, their cross product must be a `0` vector. So using,

`p x PX = 0`

`q x QX = 0`

we can construct a system of the form `Ax = 0` and solve for x.